# How to take a substring from a column in excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I have an Excel file and I want to read a specific column in that Excel file, I do that with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

file_location = input('Where is the file located? Please input the file path here. ')
column = input('In what column is the code? ')

code_array = pd.read_excel(file_location, usecols=column)
for i in code_array:
    print(code_array)
```

and that code prints out the contents of that column in the console. Now, that column has text as the following: *12345 - Description*. I only want to extract the number, how would I be able to do this? I thought of using a substring from [0:5] or converting the data into an array of string, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract Digits from Pandas column (Object dtype)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728710/extract-digits-from-pandas-column-object-dtype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the digits will be 5 digits long each time, you could do a quick substring using a lambda.

```
code_array["number_column"] = code_array["YourColumnNameHere"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:5])
```

If it will not be the same length each time, but it will be in the same position, you can split it into an array of strings, and then access the first element:

```
code_array["number_column"] = code_array["YourColumnNameHere"].apply(lambda x: str(x).split()[0])
```

Let me know if this solves your problem, otherwise we will need to use regex. NB to change YourColumnNameHere to be the same name as the column in your dataframe.

Comment: The length will always be a 5 digit number, but that implementation isn't working for me. I'm getting the following error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable @c0gnac

Comment: @JaimeMiranda try now, I have edited my answer, wrap it in a str()

Comment: @JaimeMiranda No problem! Further, if you want to extract it as an actual number, not a string, you can do int(str(x)[:5])